# Firefox and contentEditable spans

Tags: firefox, contenteditable, html

I am using a WYSIWYG (InnovaEditor) to edit content on my website, and it works in Chrome, IE, and mostly in Firefox, but FF has a slightly nasty issue. I insert `span` tags into the content to allow merging content later, such as this:

```
<span style="background-color:yellow;" 
      subst_key="{Object1.name}" 
      contentEditable="false">
  Object1 Name
</span>
```

I cannot change the basic format, it is a business project and way too much code relies on it being how it is. The issue is that, even though the `span` is not editable, FF will sometimes allow character by character deletion - just by pressing `backspace` after the merge field. Also, even after you delete the content, sometimes the `span` tag with merge field doesn't get deleted (just the text between open and close)!  Any ideas why FF allows editing of non-contentEditable fields?

TL;DR  FF occasionally allows editing of contentEditable=false `span` tag. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

well it seems the contenteditable attribute is just working in ie and some other browsers that support it
but in the other browsers there just works with the designmode attribute
maybe you have to use some javascript for it
http://theocacao.com/document.page/137

but there are also many better wysiwyg editors around like ck editor?

Comment: That link is about using contenteditable=true, and that isn't the issue at hand as the WYSIWYG already uses an I frame. Also I had enough issues getting permission to change one little feature, there is no way I would be allowed to change editors.